# approach for implementing notifications in spring web application to client

Tags: spring, notifications, client

I'm looking to build an HRMS type application to be hosted on a cloud which will serve multiple subsidiary organizations.
I would much appreciate if someone could give me a few pointers on how to go about achieving the following
A. send notifications to managers when employee performs certain actions (eg: puts in a leave request)
B. send notifications to employees when leave requests are approved/rejected
C. Some notifications will need to be within the application (as in some kind of bootstrap badge with number of new notifications; outlook or gmail style "inbox (15)" ), where as some will need to be sent out as emails or sms. so differentiating type of response to each event is also important

I saw some similar queries here but those seemed to have CometD and Atmosphere etc as suggested solutions.
my questions are 
1. since these notifications may not be in realtime (receive in realtime or near realtime when user is logged in only) do i need websockets etc or would an Ajax style polling be more appropriate?

1. There could be more than 10,000 employees (hypothetically all logged in at the same time) so will this cause an issue with those many Ajax calls to the server say every 10-15mins (using Spring web mvc to develop this)?
2. The way i envisage it in my head is to have the notifications written onto MySQL database with end user info, so that the polling will do a read on the db to check for any new notifications (polling for notification(s) will need to again cause a db write operations to mark as read).
3. What to do for someone who doesn't login for a long time and has a backlog of notifications?

Overall this approach seems like too many requests and db read/writes given the potentially large number of users expected.

Can someone please throw some light on a better way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance